# Solution to $p^3-p+1=a^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

What are the solutions to $p^3-p+1=a^2$ where $p$ is prime and $a$ is natural?
I found the solutions:

$p=3$ and $a=5$

$p=5$ and $a=11$

and one solution when $p$ is not a prime:

$p=56$ and $a=419$, i think

I don't know what to do else. I tried to find limits for $a$ or limits for $p$, I tried to do something with factoring but I got nothing. Please help.

Comment: Isn't that the equation for an elliptic curve ? If I do not miss something, the solutions for this equation can be found and there can be only finite many.

Comment: Did you try $p(p-1)(p+1)=(a-1)(a+1)$ which is equivalent to the given equation ?

Comment: It is an elliptic curve. It is always possible there is some trick that applies when $p$ is prime. What is the source of the problem

Comment: $(0/1)$ and $(1/1)$ are two more solutions , if $p$ is arbitary. For $p\le 10^8$, there are no more solutions.

Comment: @Peter , I have an elliptic curve solver for integer points, the integer points mentioned are all.

Comment: If $p$ is allowed to be negative , $(-1/1)$ is one more solution.

Comment: E.integral_points()
[(-1 : 1 : 1),
 (0 : 1 : 1),
 (1 : 1 : 1),
 (3 : 5 : 1),
 (5 : 11 : 1),
 (56 : 419 : 1)]

Comment: i tried p(p−1)(p+1)=(a−1)(a+1) but it doesn't help. What is that solver for diophantine equations, Will Jagy?

Answer (score 0):

If the equation is true, than $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$. This implies that $a \equiv 1$ or $-1 \pmod p$, since $p$ is prime.

If $a \equiv 1 \pmod p$, then $a=pk+1$. This implies that $p^2-pk^2-(2k+1)=0$. This implies that $2k+1$ is divisible by $p$. $k=\frac{pb-1}{2}$ for some natural number $b$. Putting this into our equation, notice that $(\frac{pb-1}{2})^2+b=p$ This implies that $(pb-1)^2+4b=4p$. However, since $b \ge 1$,we can say that $(pb-1)^2+4b \ge (p-1)^2+4 > 4p$ if $p \ge 7$. This implies that $p=5,2,3$. However, since $2k+1$ is divisible by $p$, $p$ is not $2$. Manual computation gives us that $p=5$

In the same way, it $a \equiv -1 \pmod p$, $p$ is 3.

Therefore, $p$ is $3$ or $5$.

Comment: How did you get that k = (pa-1)/2

Comment: Because $2k+1$ must be divisible by $p$.

Comment: when you wrote k = (pa-1)/2 did you mean "a" from the beginning equation or new "a"?

Comment: Please, I don't understand it, can you just write with more details I don't get it.?

Comment: @donaastor Added more details. My original answer was wrong, by the way, so it made sene you did not understand it.

Comment: now it's clear. thanks :)